Navigation misbehaves?
I'm a fairly inexperienced SwiftUI programmer, so I'm almost constantly confused by one thing or another. This time it's Navigation.
I want my start screen to show a List with some static content, where each line navigates to a dynamic List, where in turn I want to navigate to a view to show or edit the content of the line.
In my app, when I tap on a line to show/edit it, the app returns to the start view. I somehow messes up the navigation stack, or does somethings else wrong - but what?
I've recreated the behaviour in a small demo app:
import SwiftUI

@Observable
class InnerDataItem : Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var innerInfo = ""
    
    init(innerInfo: String = "") {
        self.innerInfo = innerInfo
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: InnerDataItem, rhs: InnerDataItem) -> Bool {
        lhs.innerInfo == rhs.innerInfo
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(innerInfo)
    }
}

@Observable
class DataModel : Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var info = "My String array"
    var innerData: [InnerDataItem] = []
    
    init(info: String = "My String array", innerData: [InnerDataItem]) {
        self.info = info
        self.innerData = innerData
    }
}

let testData = DataModel(
    info: "Data model object",
    innerData: [
        InnerDataItem(innerInfo: "(1) Inner info One"),
        InnerDataItem(innerInfo: "(1) Inner info Two"),
        InnerDataItem(innerInfo: "(1) Inner info Three"),
    ])

struct DataListView: View {
    var data: DataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        DataList(data: data)
    }
}

struct DataList: View {
    var data: DataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(data.innerData) { item in
                NavigationLink(value: item) {
                    DataLine(dataItem: item)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: InnerDataItem.self) { i in
            DataEditItem(dataItem: i)
        }
    }
}

struct DataLine: View {
    var dataItem: InnerDataItem
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(dataItem.innerInfo).font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}

struct DataEditItem: View {
    @Bindable var dataItem: InnerDataItem
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Visningsnamn")) {
                TextField("", text: $dataItem.innerInfo, prompt: Text(""))
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var gotoDataList = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Button("Link to data") {
                    gotoDataList.toggle()
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $gotoDataList) {
                DataListView(data: testData)
            }
        }
    }
}
@main
struct ListNavTestAppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

The code is updated from my original question, but it still don't work. See my comment below.

Nested ObservableObjects don't work (without a lot of work to connect them with objectWillChange). InnerDataItem should likely be a struct

You have multiple NavigationStack and you are mixing the old NavigationLink with the new navigationDestination. Stick to only 1 NavigationStack at the very top and make a complete switch to navigationDestination

Also get rid of the Hashable and Equatable conformance for InnerDataItem and add Published to the variables that should trigger a redraw such as innerInfo

Ah, it's not the first time I've done that. :-O But then how do I create a hierarchy of editable views/values in my model, so that changes are caught by SwiftUI?

@loremipsum I can't remove Hashable and Equatable, then I get compile errors.

OK, I tried to modify the code according to the comments. And converted from @ObservableObject to @Observable. The code still doesn't work, but now the error is different. Now I get a message in the console:
"A navigationDestination for “ListNavTestApp.InnerDataItem” was declared earlier on the stack.
Only the destination declared closest to the root view of the stack will be used."

Using @Observable class in SwiftUI is quite tricky because it is designed to use structs for model types but if you make the following modifications it fixes your navigation problem:
ContentView
struct ContentView: View {
    //@State private var gotoDataList = false
    @State private var dataModel: DataModel?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
//                    Button("Link to data") {
//                        gotoDataList.toggle()
//                    }
                if let dataModel {
                    NavigationLink("Link to data", value: dataModel)
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: DataModel.self) { dataModel in
                DataListView(data: dataModel)
            }
            .onAppear {
                if dataModel == nil {
                    dataModel = DataModel()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

In the above, we changed from a bool to the model for the navigation value. Since we are using @State with a class we must use an optional and init it once in .onAppear otherwise we will have a memory leak where we needlessly init the object every time the View is init. Because @State inits its initial value every time, since it is designed to use structs, i.e. value types on the memory stack, that is a negligible loss in performance. But for objects init on the heap it does matter, see using @State with @Observable in the docs for more info.
DataModel
@Observable
class DataModel: Hashable {
    var info = "My String array"
    var innerData: [InnerDataItem] = []
    
    init(testing: Bool = true) {
        if testing {
            self.info = "Data model object"
            self.innerData = [
                InnerDataItem(innerInfo: "(1) Inner info One"),
                InnerDataItem(innerInfo: "(1) Inner info Two"),
                InnerDataItem(innerInfo: "(1) Inner info Three"),
            ]
       }
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(ObjectIdentifier(self))
    }

    static func == (lhs: DataModel, rhs: DataModel) -> Bool {
        lhs === rhs
    }
}

In the above we use ObjectIdentifier for Hashable conformance and we make use of pointer comparison === to implement Equality also required by Hashable.
InnerDataItem
@Observable
class InnerDataItem: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var innerInfo: String
    
    init(innerInfo: String = "") {
        self.innerInfo = innerInfo
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }

    static func == (lhs: InnerDataItem, rhs: InnerDataItem) -> Bool {
        lhs === rhs
    }
}

In the above Identifiable provides an automatic var id when used on a  class.
